# Add data to DB from dictionary MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my system (C#, MVC, MSSQL,Entity framework) I have a Dictionary for Employee Leave Entitlement in Employee class.

```
 public Dictionary<string, EmployeeLeaveEntitlement> LeaveEntitlementDetails { get; internal set; }
```

EmployeeLeaveEntitlement class as follows,

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of the leave.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The type of the leave.</value>
    public string LeaveType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the entitlement.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The entitlement.</value>
    public double Entitlement { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the availed count.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The availed count.</value>
    public double AvailedCount { get; set; }
```

What i need is, connect a database to the system,
I already Created context for employee,

```
 public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

when I run the system it will create database but there are no table or column for the Leave Entitlement..Is there a way to add data to database from a Dictionary?

Help me

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary types can not be mapped with Entity Framework.

I do not know what you represent by the key of the dictionary, but you can create a new intermediate entity with keys of `Employee`, `EmployeeLeaveEntitlement` and dictionary key and map this as a collection in your `Employee` class

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public string DictionaryKey { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeLeaveEntitlementId { get; set; }

}

public class Employee
{
    // other properties

    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }     
}
```